# how to catch spring mvc mapping not found, i am using spring mvc 3.2.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
INFO: PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/appName/requestMapping/methodName] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Hi 
I am getting this error while the requested page is not availabe, my requirement is if requested url is not available then check that requested URL with database and perform some actions so I want to catch this, it would be great if anyone can help me in this,

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this, you can define an `<error-page>` entry in your web.xml with error code of `404`:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
```

and define a handler method to handle `404` mapping:

```
@RequestMapping("404")
public String handlePageNotFound(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //this will return you the original URL for which this 404 happened     
    String originalUri = (String) request
            .getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
    //here you can write your code to handle this 404 error
    ...
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for replying , ya this works but I am not getting the URL, it is returning null.

Comment: try this :    `request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);`

Comment: how the request is coming to a non-existent URL. is the user is typing something in the browser or is it a redirect request?

Comment: yes user is typing  URL in browser, if url is not present then as you have described I can catch it and show a page for that but getting NULL as previous url , i need this url to parse it and search content from database.

Comment: any security-constraint on your web application? and on which server it is running?

Comment: i haven't specified any security constraint , I am using glassfish 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the requested url like this..

```
@RequestMapping("404")
public String handlePageNotFound(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //this will return you the original URL for which this 404 happened     
   String originalUri = (String) request
                    .getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri");

}
```